# I am trying to extract text from .pdf file and get certain information to store in my object, what is the best way to do it in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf

I have specific .pdf file that I want to extract some information using code, the pdf will always be the same format but the information such as name will change and from it I need to extract some information like address, name, phoneNumber etc. This needs to be done on front end and i will get that .pdf file in input field type="file". What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Is it better to do extraction on server or on front-end?

Comment: I want to have one input type="file" where user will have option to upload pdf file, then my code needs to get some information from that pdf and fill my form, the form already exists, now client want me to create that "PDF feature" so he can quick fill the form using specific PDF file... Also thanks for helping...